# Add ckeditor widget to a custom toolbar

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to add the [placeholder](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/placeholder) widget to my custom toolbar[image]- for the 
life of me I can't figure out how:

`<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.2/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>`

It works with the default toolbar:

`<textarea cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10">test1</textarea>`

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
  extraPlugins: 'placeholder',
  height: 50
} );
```

But not with a custom toolbar:

`<textarea cols="80" id="editor2" name="editor2" rows="10">test2</textarea>`

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2', {
  extraPlugins: 'placeholder',
  height: 50,
  toolbar: [{ name: 'tools',group: 'tools', items: [ 'Bold','Placeholder', 'Redo' ], groups: [ 'tools'] }]
} );
```

As I understand it there are 2 ways to insert a button to toolbar:
  1. use name in toolbar itself (editor 2 example)
  2. using `editor.ui.addButton` function:

```
editor.ui.addButton && editor.ui.addButton( 'CreatePlaceholder', {
                label: lang.toolbar,
                command: 'placeholder',
            //  toolbar: 'insert,5',
                toolbar: 'clipboard,0',
                icon: 'placeholder'
            } );
```

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjv0azo9/18/) to show:

1. a default toolbar with a Placeholder button
2. a custom toolbar that I can't add Placeholder button to

Can you please show/tell me how to add Placeholder to a custom made toolbar? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have named your button 'CreatePlaceholder', so you should use this name in toolbar.

```
editor.ui.addButton && editor.ui.addButton( 'CreatePlaceholder', ...

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor3', {
    ...
    toolbar: [{ name: 'tools',group: 'tools', items: [ 'Bold','CreatePlaceholder', ...
```

Full code:
http://jsfiddle.net/nw3o4gy5/

Also take a look at [CKEDITOR.ui.addButton](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_ui.html#method-addButton).